# Почему не работает переключение картинки назад в слайдере?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var perv = document.querySelector('.perv');
perv.addEventListener('click', pervPict());

var slideIndex = 2;


function pervPict() {
 slideIndex = slideIndex - 1;
 imgslider = document.querySelectorAll('.imgslider');
  imgslider[slideIndex].style.zIndex = slideIndex + 10;
}
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

.slider > img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 50px;
}

.perv img, .next img {
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.perv img {
  left: 10px;
  top: 130px;
}

.next img {
  right: 10px;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="perv">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/no-translate-detected_318-32320.jpg" alt="" class="imgslider">
</div>
  <img src="http://www.pptbackgrounds.org/thumb/elegant-grey-illumination-background-presentations-powerpoint-backgrounds.jpg" class="imgslider" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.ltcompany.com/media/cache/be/80/be80af385feb473e80c52e477c7702f2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://kaspi.kz/medias/sys_master/images/images/he6/he3/9067394891806/samsung-ue43m5500-black-1801318-4.png" class="imgslider" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1244/3074/products/Tiem_Slipstream_black_-1-web_400x.jpg?v=1508257699" class="imgslider" alt="">
  <img src="http://mediaryazan.ru/my_pictures/2011/02/00002.jpg" class="imgslider" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.paulturkowski.com/wp-content/themes/invictus_3.3.2/timthumb.php?src=http://www.paulturkowski.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/ElektraBregenz2.jpg&h=300&w=400&a=c&q=100" class="imgslider" alt="">
  <div class="next">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Chevron_right_font_awesome.svg/768px-Chevron_right_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Попытался написать слайдер, на данном этапе возникла проблема. А именно
TypeError: imgslider[slideIndex] is undefined

Переменная в глобальной области видимости, почему внутри функции она не видна?

Comment: для начала - при добавлении обработчика события - обработчик запускать не нужно. `perv.addEventListener('click', pervPict);` Слайдер начнет немного работать.

Comment: @Дмытрык Спасибо, дальше сам :) Я просто не заметил)

Comment: Ну и слайдер у Вас не дописан, он работает в только в сторону уменьшения `slideIndex = slideIndex - 1;` Еще нужно написать код, который будет работать в строну увеличения `slideIndex ++`

Comment: Да, я написал выше, что проблема возникла на этой стадии написания. Сейчас дальше писать буду слайдер.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi только не `perv`, а `prev`))